# What to do when you discover a question is deeply flawed, and fixing it IS the answer?

Tags: discussion

I've asked a question, but realised that the question is flawed. It was basically comparing two variables and asking 'why are they different' but on investigation, they are not the same type at all.

What's the correct action now? Editing to fix the question invalidates it. Should I answer my own question with the fix, or delete the question entirely?

Comment: It sounds like you hadn't done enough research *before* asking the question; I'd be inclined to cut my losses and delete, in your position.

Comment: Depends on the question - if knowledge about the fix is likely to help future generations, then it might be worth keeping around. Otherwise, deleting is probably indeed the best option.